# Seaborn violin plot for pandas data

Tags: python, boxplot, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a pandas dataframe heights_table with following info:
Columns: Age, Height. Rows: each person in data set

I want to generate a seaborn violin plot from this data. On the x-axis I want range of ages, and on the y axis, I want a 'blob' of height distributions for each of these ages. I know how to do a boxplot for this:

```
heights_table.boxplot(by='age')
```

How can I do a violin plot in seaborn for this? I have tried to read documentation [here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/elaborate_violinplot.html), but couldn't get it to work. Any help with be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean you "couldn't get it to work?" Most people here will probably just direct you towards those docs unless you have a specific error or issue. It would be helpful if you provided an actual attempt here (i.e. code).

Comment: Include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I am confused with what groupby(level="network") means in that doc. I just have a dataframe with the 'age' and 'height' columns. The line get_level_values("network") does not work for me.

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for 
sns.violinplot(x="age", y="height", data=heights_table)